# C++ AES OpenSSL

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm trying to read a string from a file encrypt it with AES and then save it to other file. Later I need to read the new file, decrypt and save the output to a new file again. The problem is some strange character are appearing.

```
int Crypt::__aesEncrypt(const unsigned char *msg, size_t msgLen, unsigned char **encMsg) {
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *aesEncryptCtx = (EVP_CIPHER_CTX*)malloc(sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX));
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(aesEncryptCtx);

unsigned char *aesKey = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_KEYLEN/8);
unsigned char *aesIV = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_KEYLEN/8);

unsigned char *aesPass = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_KEYLEN/8);
unsigned char *aesSalt = (unsigned char*)malloc(8);

if(RAND_bytes(aesPass, AES_KEYLEN/8) == 0) {
    return FAILURE;
}

if(RAND_bytes(aesSalt, 8) == 0) {
    return FAILURE;
}

if(EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), aesSalt, aesPass, AES_KEYLEN/8, AES_ROUNDS, aesKey, aesIV) == 0) {
    return FAILURE;
}

strncpy((char*)aesKey, (const char*)"B374A26A714904AAB374A26A714904AA", AES_KEYLEN/8);
strncpy((char*)aesIV, (const char*)"B374A26A714904AA", AES_KEYLEN/16);

size_t blockLen = 0;
size_t encMsgLen = 0;

*encMsg = (unsigned char*)malloc(msgLen + AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
if(encMsg == NULL) return FAILURE;
(*encMsg)[0] = '\0';

if(!EVP_EncryptInit_ex(aesEncryptCtx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, aesKey, aesIV)) {
    return FAILURE;
}

if(!EVP_EncryptUpdate(aesEncryptCtx, *encMsg, (int*)&blockLen, (unsigned char*)msg, msgLen)) {
    return FAILURE;
}
encMsgLen += blockLen;

if(!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(aesEncryptCtx, *encMsg + encMsgLen, (int*)&blockLen)) {
    return FAILURE;
}

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(aesEncryptCtx);
free(aesEncryptCtx);

free(aesKey);
free(aesIV);

return encMsgLen + blockLen;
}

int Crypt::__aesDecrypt(unsigned char *encMsg, size_t encMsgLen, char **decMsg) {
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *aesDecryptCtx = (EVP_CIPHER_CTX*)malloc(sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX));
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(aesDecryptCtx);

unsigned char *aesKey;
unsigned char *aesIV;

aesKey = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_KEYLEN/8);
aesIV = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_KEYLEN/8);

unsigned char *aesPass = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_KEYLEN/8);
unsigned char *aesSalt = (unsigned char*)malloc(8);

if(RAND_bytes(aesPass, AES_KEYLEN/8) == 0) {
    return FAILURE;
}

if(RAND_bytes(aesSalt, 8) == 0) {
    return FAILURE;
}

if(EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), aesSalt, aesPass, AES_KEYLEN/8, AES_ROUNDS, aesKey, aesIV) == 0) {
    return FAILURE;
}

strncpy((char*)aesKey, (const char*)"B374A26A714904AAB374A26A714904AA", AES_KEYLEN/8);
strncpy((char*)aesIV, (const char*)"B374A26A714904AA", AES_KEYLEN/16);

size_t decLen = 0;
size_t blockLen = 0;

*decMsg = (char*)malloc(encMsgLen);
if(*decMsg == NULL) return FAILURE;

if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(aesDecryptCtx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, aesKey, aesIV)) {
    return FAILURE;
}

if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(aesDecryptCtx, (unsigned char*)*decMsg, (int*)&blockLen, encMsg, (int)encMsgLen)) {
    return FAILURE;
}
decLen += blockLen;

if(!EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(aesDecryptCtx, (unsigned char*)*decMsg + decLen, (int*)&blockLen)) {
    return FAILURE;
}
decLen += blockLen;

(*decMsg)[decLen] = '\0';

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(aesDecryptCtx);

return encMsgLen;
}
```

Encrypting:

```
    unsigned char *encMsg = NULL;
    int size = __aesEncrypt((const unsigned char*)decrypted_string.c_str(), decrypted_string.size(), &encMsg);


    return std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(encMsg), size);
```

Decrypting:

```
    char *decMsg = NULL;
    int size = __aesDecrypt((unsigned char*)encrypted_string.c_str(), encrypted_string.size(), &decMsg);

    return std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(decMsg), size);
```

I can successfully crypt and decrypt, but some strange characters are appearing at the end of the encrypted file, they are like empty spaces:

Comment: These lines look questionable strncpy((char*)aesKey, (const char*)"B374A26A714904AAB374A26A714904AA", AES_KEYLEN/8); since it is only using 16 bytes of that 32-byte string as the key.

Answer (score 2):

AES is a block cypher. It takes blocks of 16 bytes, and encrypt them into a block of 16 byets. If you try to use it with data whose length is not a multiple of 16, padding (usually random data) is added to round it up to a multiple of 16 bytes. You need to manage the length of the data yourself.

Example:

```
int encryptHelper(const string& msg, ...)
{
    uint32_t msgSize = msg.length();
    newMsg.push_back((msgSize >> 0)  & 0xFF);
    newMsg.push_back((msgSize >> 8)  & 0xFF);
    newMsg.push_back((msgSize >> 16) & 0xFF);
    newMsg.push_back((msgSize >> 24) & 0xFF);
    string newMsg(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&msgSize), sizeof(msgSize));
    newMsg += msg;
    return __aesEncrypt(newMsg.c_str(), newMsg.length(), ...);
}

int decryptHelper(const string& encrypted, ...)
{
    string msg = ... whatever you are doing to decrypt
    uint32_t actualSize = 0;
    // remove signal first, then widen
    actualSize |= static_cast<uint32_t>(static_cast<unsigned char>(msg[0])) << 0;
    actualSize |= static_cast<uint32_t>(static_cast<unsigned char>(msg[1])) << 8;
    actualSize |= static_cast<uint32_t>(static_cast<unsigned char>(msg[2])) << 16;
    actualSize |= static_cast<uint32_t>(static_cast<unsigned char>(msg[3])) << 24;
    string actualMsg = msg.substr(4, actualSize);
    ...
}
```

I didn't bother to write the exact code to call your functions because all that casting and memory leaking gave me nausea. Fill in the blanks.

Comment: Prepending an integer with the length is one way. Controlling how padding is done is another way (although you don't want to just append NULL bytes, as it can lower the security if the last block is composed mostly of zero bytes).

Comment: Sometimes OpenSSL pads with a byte value that is the number of bytes of padding.  So if the last block has 7 bytes, there are 9 bytes of padding so it might pad with 9x '\9' bytes.

Comment: @brianbeuning Yes, that's PKCS #5: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2898 There are also other ways to do it.

Comment: @DanielKO Yes, AES is a block cipher, but no, OP is using the `EVP_EncryptUpdate` and `EVP_EncryptFinal` functions that take care of padding for the caller. It isn't necessary to break the data into 16 byte increments or pad the final block yourself.